# How can I extract coordinates of the nodes of my graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have this output for my graph.

```
In[85]:= PropertyList[{g, 1}]

Out[85]= {"TerminalsCoordinates", VertexCoordinates, VertexShape, VertexShapeFunction, VertexSize, VertexStyle}`
```

How can I extract the vertices info separately to different sets?

Comment: Did you click on the "show complete *Mathematica* input" button, for starters?

Comment: Sorry I am new here and don't know how to ask the questions?Could you please tell me how to ask that kind of questions??

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by (**answering questions**) in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [FAQs](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)! 3) When you see good [Q&A](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t) (I stole this text from Vitaly)

Comment: Thats great!!!I didn't know that.Many thanks for advices!!

Comment: In v9, `GraphEmbedding[g]` will give the vertex coordinates.

Comment: Great command in V9.but it gives the vertex coordinates.The data that I am dealing with has defined "TerminalsCoordinates" for each Vertex.I want to extract the first coordinate here for each vertex.

Comment: `PropertyValue[{g, 1}, "TerminalsCoordinates"]` gives me the 215 coordinates in the fist node.I have 2404 nodes.Could you please tell me how is the extraction algorithm for first coordinates of each node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract first coordinates of TerminalsCoordinates for each node:

```
(PropertyValue[{g,#}, "TerminalsCoordinates"]& /@ VertexList[g])[[All,1]]
```